# iOS - expecting unreasonable character

Tags: ios, objective-c, brackets

I am getting a weird error in my Xcode compiler when doing app for iPhone. The error I get is:

`Expected ']'`

```
- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults* standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if(standardUserDefaults)
    {
        NSString* isNewNote = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"newNote"]; // here is the error
        if(isNewNote isEqualToString:@"Yes")
        {
            [noteList removeObjectAtIndex:currentNote];
            [noteContent removeObjectAtIndex:currentNote];
        }
    }

    NSString* storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Can you figure out whats wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `if(isNewNote isEqualToString:@"Yes")` -- did the Xcode tell you which line the error was on?

Comment: Yes.

`NSString* isNewNote = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"newNote"]; // here is the error`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
if(isNewNote isEqualToString:@"Yes")
```

Should be this:

```
if([isNewNote isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
```

Comment: Even better would be to store that value as a `BOOL` instead of a string.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I guess I'm just really tired. Anyways, I can mark your answer as solving in 9 minutes. Thank you very much.